# Specifying format: "xml" ignored with render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, actionview, actioncontroller

I have an action that needs to render a view to string. The view is called index.xml.erb. I am trying to achieve this with render_to_string:

```
my_string = render_to_string(layout: false, format: "xml")
```

render_to_string is instead rendering the contents of index.html.erb and assigning it to my_string. What am I missing?

**Note**: I am aware that I can do something like this:

```
my_string = render_to_string(:action => "#{self.action_name}.xml.erb")
```

But I'm curious as to why the "format" option isn't honored with render_to_string.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This works for me.

`render_to_string( :action => "#{self.action_name}", :formats => [:xml] )`

Comment: Geez, 7yrs later and this answer got me out of a headache trying to grab some pdf templates on a json request. Thanks for contributing.